# mouseleave event getting called multiple times in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have images in Tab, two events are attached with it mouseenter and mouseleave, as soon as mouse leaves image the mouse leave event should get called one time but it is getting called 3 to 4 times how to avoid this.

below is my code

```
private void AddImageInTab(TabItemEx tiex, ref int Col, ref int Row, int j, System.Windows.Controls.Image bmp, XmlNode Node, WrapPanel wrapPanel)
        {
            try
            {
                //some logic here
                bmp.MouseLeave += bmp_MouseLeave;
                bmp.MouseEnter += bmp_MouseEnter;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Validate.LogException(ex);
            }
        }

    private int mouseEnterCount = 0;

    void bmp_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseEnterCount == 1)
        {
            mouseEnterCount = 0;
            if (tooltip != null)
            {
                tooltip.Close();
                tooltip = null;
                e.Handled = true;
            } 
        }
    }

    void bmp_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (++mouseEnterCount == 1)
        {
            if (tooltip != null)
                e.Handled = true;

            if (tooltip == null || !tooltip.IsOpen)
            {
                Image img = ((Image)sender);
                if (img.Name != string.Empty)
                {
                    string[] values = ((Image)sender).Tag.ToString().Split(new[] { SPLIT_PATTERN }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string sizesTemp = GetSizesInFormat(values[4]);

                    if (values[0] != "pipeTypeItems" && values[values.Length - 2] == "False")
                    {
                        img.Cursor = Cursors.No;
                        tooltip_Information(img, sizesTemp);
                    }
                    else
                        tooltip_Information(img, sizesTemp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tooltip.ResetTimer();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: How and when do you attach the event handlers? Show your code first.

Comment: Have you perhaps attached to the event multiple times?

Comment: can  we have some code please ?

Comment: How and where do you attach bmp_MouseLeave to the event?

Comment: i have edited post, in function AddImageInTab i am attaching mouseleave event.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use WPF with WinForms in mind. WPF isn't meant to be used that way.

First design your view model :

```
public class ImageViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Bitmap{ get; set; }
    public string BitmapInfo { 
        get { 
            return string.Format("{0}x{1}", Bitmap.PixelWidth, Bitmap.PixelHeight);
        }
    }
    public bool CanBrowse { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then design your view :

```
<Window ...>
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image 
          Source="{Binding Bitmap}"
          ToolTip="{Binding BitmapInfo}"
          Cursor="{Binding CanBrowse, Converter={x:Static BoolToCursorConverter.Instance}}"
          />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>
</Window>
```

And bind them together

```
var images = new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();

// fill images

var view = new ImagesView();
view.DataContext = images;
```